# Не открывается сайт в VmWare Workstation в браузере Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, dns, vmware

У меня проблема следующего характера. Я установил VmWare Workstation на Windows 10. В нём на одной машине запустил Ubuntu Server 16.04 (не Desktop). На ней установил сайт. Сайт установился правильно: там проблем нет. php, nginx, composer, ftp и т.д. нормально функционируют. Мне надо чтобы в браузере Windows 10, на котором установлена VmWare, на моём компьютере открывался этот сайт. Там, наверно DNS надо прописать. Вот картинка с сетями в VmWare:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Чтобы сайт запускался в Windows 10 в браузере хотя бы под ip.

Comment: Тип сети какой выбрали при создании вм?

Comment: Тип сети при установке host-only. Разве его сейчас нельзя сменить? На NAT или Bridget. Или всё? Уже поздно?

Comment: Все можно. На host-only должен отвечать на 192.168.206.128 в вашем случае

Comment: Стоп, разглядел на картинке, что это нат. Переключитесь на хост-онли и посмотрите, какой адрес получит на виртуалке. К нему и подключайтесь

Comment: Да, получилось. Адрес получился http://192.168.1.5/ . Вывелась страница "Welcome to nginx". Но сайт, прописанный в sites-available не выводится на страницу браузера. Но это из другой оперы. Спасибо большое.

Comment: на windows в файле c:\windows\system32\drivers\hosts пропишите 192.168.1.5 mysite.local

Comment: Это я, конечно, знаю. Проблема в другом: При наборе 192.168.1.5 должен выходить тот сайт на UBUNTU (я даже не знаю как там выглядит индексная страница), а не Welcome to nginx. Вот отрывок от прописки сайта в sites-available : server_name repost.dev   root ...... index index.php и т.д. На какую же папку ссылается http://192.168.1.5/ в браузере?

Comment: В nginx при установке создается страница "поумолчанию" welcome... + сайты, которые вы добавите по доменным именам. Если неизвестно к какому из сайтов идет запрос, то откроется welcome

Comment: Я обращался к сайту в браузере http://repost.dev, но пишется, что не находится ip-адрес сайта. Он прописан в sites-available именно так.

Comment: а в hosts? Вы же открываете его на своей машине, которая не знает о настройках в виртуальной

Comment: А как же сделать чтобы знал? Если прописать dns - прокатит? Ведь браузер в Windows 10 будет просто рассматривать его как удалённый сервер с прописанным dns, но находиться он будет на том же самом компьютере.

Comment: Я ж уже писал. На своем windows-компьютере 
 в файле c:\windows\system32\drivers\hosts пропишите 192.168.1.5 repost.dev После этого, когда в браузере наберете "repost.dev", то он уже будет знать по какому адресу идти, а в заголовке запроса будет repost.dev, по которому nginx определит, какой сайт будет отвечать

Comment: Я прописал, но у меня ничего не вышло.